# Python - UDP screenshare

Tags: python, sockets, udp, client-server, screensharing

I am having problems with UDP screenshot transmission. I'm trying through UDP sockets to constantly transmit screenshots of a screen to show them on the other side (client sends images, server shows 'em). I already have it with TCP, but having it in UDP would be nice aswell.

code:
**Server Side**

```
import socket
import threading
from zlib import decompress

import pygame

WIDTH = 1900
HEIGHT = 1000
host = '192.168.1.42'
port=5000

def reunitepixels(lst):
    data = ''
    for i in range(0,10):
        data =data + string.from_bytes(lst.pop(0), byteorder = 'big')
    bytedata = bytes(data, 'utf-8')
    return bytedata

def recvall(UDPServerSocket, length):
    
    """ Retreive all pixels. """

    buf = b''
    while len(buf) < length:
        data = UDPServerSocket.recvfrom(length - len(buf))
        if not data:
            return data
        buf += data
    return buf

def ScreenShare(conn):
    pixels_lst =[] #list of byte chunks 
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((950, 500))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    watching = True
    while watching:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    watching = False
                    break
        # Retreive the size of the pixels length, the pixels length and pixels
        size_len = int.from_bytes(conn.recvfrom(1024), byteorder='big')
        size = int.from_bytes(recvall(conn, size_len), byteorder='big')
        for i in range(1,11):
            pixels_lst.append(conn.recvfrom(size))
        pixels = decompress(reunitepixels(pixels_lst), 6)
        # Create the Surface from raw pixels
        img = pygame.image.fromstring(pixels, (WIDTH, HEIGHT), 'RGB')
        # Display the picture
        screen.blit(img, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
def main():
    UDPServerSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    UDPServerSocket.bind((host, port))
    try:
        print('Server started.')
        thread = threading.Thread(target=ScreenShare, args=(UDPServerSocket,))
        thread.start()
    finally:
        UDPServerSocket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Client Side**

```
import socket
import zlib

import mss

WIDTH = 1900
HEIGHT = 1000
host = '192.168.1.42'
port=5000

LocalHost = ((host,port))

def split_img(seq, chunk, skip_tail=False):
    lst = []
    if chunk <= len(seq):
        lst.extend([seq[:chunk]])
        lst.extend(split_img(seq[chunk:], chunk, skip_tail))
    elif not skip_tail and seq:
        lst.extend([seq])
    return lst

def retreive_screenshot(sock):
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        # The region to capture
        rect = {'top': 0, 'left': 0, 'width': WIDTH, 'height': HEIGHT}

        while True:
            sliced_image = []
            img = sct.grab(rect)
            pixels = zlib.compress(img.rgb, 6)
            sliced_image = split_img(pixels,int(len(pixels)/10))
            break
            size = len(pixels)
            size_len = (size.bit_length() + 7) // 8
            sock.sendto(bytes([size_len]), LocalHost)

            # Send the actual pixels length
            size_bytes = size.to_bytes(size_len, 'big')
            sock.sendto(size_bytes, LocalHost)
            # Send pixels
            for i in sliced_image:
                sock.sendto(sliced_image.pop(0), LocalHost)

def main():
    watching = True    

    UDPClientSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    try:
        while 'connected':
            retreive_screenshot(UDPClientSocket)
    finally:
        UDPClientSocket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm trying to split the compressed byte variable 'pixels' on the client side into a number of chunks, then send each of them to the server side, which will 'mend' them back together and form the complete screenshot.

*Update*
I saw after i posted that i had some obvious problems which i had not seen before, since it never got to the function of the thread since it crashed practically immediately. Above is latest code, and it gives error 10038, which I'm trying to fix atm. still, the original question of the post remains.

Comment: What exactly is your question about this code?

Comment: Let me just clarify what happens - pygame window which is supposed to show the photo just freezes up and collapses.

Comment: my question is how can i split up the compressed image and then reconnect it without it being botched up, I guess

Comment: One big problem I see on the server side is that you're infinitely creating new threads with instances of `ScreenShare`, which will likely lead the application to thrash eventually.

Comment: what do you mean? I kept the same structure from when i was using TCP and it was fine. btw, i think i found myself some problem - it seems that me decoding the compressed bytes with utf-8 is... illegal. so I need to find some other way to add them up like a string when its a byte.

Comment: Oh, i understand now what you meant. definitely right about that Stephen, i removed the sock.accept() part and didnt notice it was completely changing the freeze before creating a new thread. thanks for helping ^^